# Why is a parent div not increased in height by a child div?

Tags: html, css

If a parent div (`container`) has a `height: 0px` and a child div (`block`) inside that element has a height set, how come the child div doesn't push the parent div to be the height of the child div? Or - how come you can see the child div at all if the parent's height is 0?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkd5bcsu/2/)

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    block
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.container` div doesn't grow because you've explicitly set the height.  The reason the child shows is because the `overflow` property is apparently defaulted to `visible`; if you want the child hidden you can set `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    block
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> how come the child div doesn't push the parent div to be the height of the child div?

You told it to render it at a height of `0px` so it renders it at a height of `0px`.

`height` is not [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height).

> Or - how come you can see the child div at all if the parent's height is 0?

The default value of [the `overflow` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for most elements is `visible`.

Answer (score 1):

> how come the child div doesn't push the parent div to be the height of the child div?

Because you force it to render on `0px` due the `height: 0px;`

---

> How come you can see the child div at all if the parent's height is 0?

You're seeing the `overflow` of the element. To prevent this behaviour, set `overflow` to `hidden`:

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    block
  </div>
</div>
```